# integrating qt interface and ros code

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am very new in ROS ans qt.I have an ros code that move the robot with a fixed velocity. Now I want to move it with a parametric velocity and assign the velocity input via an interface developed by qt. I have written the code(c++)and developped the interface but I do not know how to integrate them. Thanks for your replies

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62214/integrating-qt-interface-and-ros-code/) by [bayramalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/4832/bayramalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to integrate your `Qt`-based GUI and `ROS` is to use [qt_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_ros) package. Work on its [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates) to get an idea how it works. In a nutshell, that pkg provides an interface component `qnode` where you can pass `ROS` values to `Qt` and vice versa.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1